# How to modify webpack's html-loader options in vue.config.js?

Tags: vue.js, webpack

Webpack's `html-loader` works fine in vue without any config:

`import my_tpl from 'html-loader!@/assets/my_tpl.html'`

I'd like to change an option, set minimize to false:
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader/blob/ee30fe6cbf36c7fbf05c4153475deed8f3946240/README.md

According to https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#modifying-options-of-a-plugin
I've added this to vue.config.js

```
    chainWebpack: config => {
        config.plugin('html').tap(args => {
            args[0].minimize = false
            return args
        })
    },
```

but it has no effect on production (development already has minimize=false by default).

How to change html-loader options in vue.config.js?